# Not able to delete 2sxc view

Tags: 2sxc

I'm not able to delete a 2sxc view. getting a warning

"Had an erro talking to the server (status 400).
Massage:Bad Request
Detail:found 2 relationship where this child - the parents are:3854 (2sexyContent-ContentGroup), 3897 (2sexyContent-ContentGroup)."

Please find warning image attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means the template is still in use. You can either find out where exactly, delete the module and the dnn-trash, then you can delete.

Alternately you can force-delete it (not recommended). To Force-delete, go to "Data" and switch to debug-mode and change scope to "2SexyContent-System" http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/advanced-dynamic-data-content-understanding-content-type-scopes.

There you'll find the content-item describing the template, which you can delete, and force-delete.

Comment: I think wanted a dash "-" in between 2SexyContent and System. At least that's what worked for me: 2SexyContent-System