# Server 500 while accessing 2SexyContent-ContentGroup

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I am trying to delete a view by following instructions here: [Not able to delete 2sxc view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928172/not-able-to-delete-2sxc-view) and here: http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/advanced-dynamic-data-content-understanding-content-type-scopes

I can get to the 2SexyContent-System scope without difficulty but when I try the 2SexyContent-ContentGroup I get a Server 500. 2SexyContent-Template and the other types work just fine. Error is below.

Note I realize the ContentGroup may not even be helpful to me.  I do understand Template is where I could ForceDelete but I would like to avoid that.  I was hoping ContentGroup might help me locate the parent entities that I need to remove.  We have a large site and use 2sxc a lot so I am trying to discover the best way to find these parents and delete them in a healthy way.

```
Message: Had an error talking to the server (status 500).
Detail: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content 'application/json;charset=utf-8'.

Get [server name removed]/en-us/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/eav/entities/GetAllOfTypeForAdmin?appId=2&contentType=2SexyContent-ContentGroup 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @   VM10361:2
(anonymous) @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:103
n   @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:99
(anonymous) @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:96
(anonymous) @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:131
$eval   @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:145
$digest @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:142
$apply  @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:146
(anonymous) @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:276
Sf  @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:37
d   @   set.min.js?sxcver=8.9.1.13916:37
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Content-Group is almost certainly the wrong way to do this, because the ContentGroup is the subset of items assigned to the current module/instance.

If you're trying to support force-delete, best check out how the admin-UI does it.